# I'm unable to run "jhipster jdl domain.jdl" to update an application On windows 11

Tags: jhipster

I'm using jhipster 7.9.3, and node v18.16.0 on windows 11

I have an application that was generated using "jhipster" and then "jhipster jdl ./domain.jdl"

When I try to update the domain using the same command (jhipster jdl ./domain.jdl),
I get to the point where it prompts: ? Overwrite src\main\webapp\app\entities\schedule\list\schedule.component.html? (ynarxdeiH)

but it doesn't accept the input of any of those options. It just freezes and needs to be killed.

I've tried different versions of node, different changes to the JDL, and running the jhipster an admin window and a bash window.

Comment: It should work with Node 16.

Comment: Thanks. It eventually worked, but it took about 20 minutes to complete what normally takes a few seconds, and now it's back to normal.